# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add a new column called `[Scanned]` to my SQL Server table, `[master].[dbo].[TEST_concat]`.

However, I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

Code:

```
SELECT TOP (11000) 
    filer_id
    ,[filerName]
    ,[ResourceName]
    ,[UniqueIdentity]
    ,[DirID]
    ,[DirsCount]
    ,[PermCount]
    ,[RowID]
    ,[ResourceType]
    ,[ResourceFlags]
    ,[Hresult]
    ,[Details]
    ,[fsid]
    ,[Protocol]
    ,[vExport]
    ,[filerType]
    ,[Error Messages]
FROM 
    [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat]

ALTER TABLE dbo.TEST_concat
ADD [Scanned] AS
    CASE WHEN [DirID] > 0 AND [DirsCount] IS NULL 
            THEN 'in Shares table, but not SortedDirectoryTree properties'
         WHEN [DirID] > 0 AND  [DirsCount] > 0 
            THEN 'Yes'
         WHEN [DirID] IS NULL AND [DirsCount] IS NULL
            THEN 'No'
         ELSE ' ' 
    END
```

This is what my results look like with the error message:

[image]

The results should be all filled out with thousands of lines.

Comment: Shouldn't you be declaring a data type for [Scanned] such as [Scanned] varchar(50) or something like that

Comment: @RyanWilson not if the column is a Computed Column, no. The problem, however, seems like the datatype of `DirID` or `DirsCount` is not an `int`. Thus, because of the (poor) data choice, someone has inserted the literal string `'NULL'`, rather than the value *`NULL`*. @ the OP, find the offending rows, update their values, and fix your datatype. I suggest using `SELECT DirID, DirsCount FROM [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat] WHERE (TRY_CONVERT(int,DirID) IS NULL AND DirID IS NOT NULL) OR (TRY_CONVERT(int, DirsCount) IS NULL AND DirsCount IS NOT NULL);` to find the offending rows/values.

Comment: It looks like you have 'NULL' (as string) instead of NULL data

Comment: @larnu interesting about Computed Column, never used that before. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RyanWilson they're very useful, especially if they're `PERSISTED`; as then they also can be indexed (Computed Columns that aren't `PERSISTED` can't be indexed). I'd suggest looking them up. :)

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, I was just reading about them. Thanks for the suggestion. Quick question, in the OP's example it would seem that as a Computed Column the datatype would not change as they are setting its value to a varchar/nvarchar, could you give me an example of a Computed Column where you wouldn't know the data type at creation?

Comment: @RyanWilson you can't create a computed column that doesn't have a deterministic datatype. If you're using an expression, data type precedence would be used to predetermine the datatype. If that expression generates as error then you'll know either at the point of trying to add the column, or when updating or inserting the data.

Comment: @Larnu I just read a post about how all Computed Columns are deterministic, thanks for that. I guess I was trying to find a real world example of when you would want to use a Computed Column, but in the aforementioned post I saw how one person was using it to multiply an int with a money type for a computed column value.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't question this before either; why are you creating objects in `master`? Generally this is a bad idea, even if they are test object..If you want test create a test/sandbox database.

Answer (score 2):

Going to post this as an answer, just to expand a little bit.

Firstly, the problem appears to be that `DirID` or `DirCount` aren't the datatype `int` but are a `varchar` or similar. Thus, as a result of the data choice, someone has inserted the literal string value `'NULL'`, rather than the value *`NULL`*. If you run the query `SELECT CONVERT(int, 'NULL');` you'll see that you get the same error the OP has.

The real solution here, therefore, is to fix the data and the datatype. Firstly, you'll need to find the bad values. This can be done with:

```
SELECT DirID, DirsCount
FROM [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat]
WHERE (TRY_CONVERT(int,DirID) IS NULL AND DirID IS NOT NULL)
   OR (TRY_CONVERT(int, DirsCount) IS NULL AND DirsCount IS NOT NULL);
```

I'd check this data over first. if you're happy that all of these values can be updated with *`NULL`* then you do 2 separate `UPDATE` statements (you might not need both of these):

```
UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat]
SET DirID = NULL
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,DirID) IS NULL AND DirID IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat]
SET DirsCount = NULL
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int,DirsCount ) IS NULL AND DirsCount IS NOT NULL;
```

We should probably, now, look at correcting the datatype. This can be done with:

```
ALTER [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat] ALTER DirID int;
ALTER [master].[dbo].[TEST_concat] ALTER DirsCount int;
```

Now, you can run your other `ALTER` command that you have in your intial post.

Of course, this strongly assumes that `DirID` and `DirsCount` should have an `int` (or decimal) value (if decimal, then replace all references to `int` with `decimal(s,p)`, where `s` and `p` are your required scale and precision). If they *can* have other values then that's a completely different kettle of fish. I imagine that `[DirsCount] > '0'` may held incorrect results, as (for example) `'a' > '0'`. For example try:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'a' > '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Notice the result value is `1`.

Comment: Interesting that this had the solution marker removed. @Ruth what changed? You haven't commented or edited your question; if you do I'll be more than happy to expand on my answer.